# How to fetch the result after sending a get request to Koa application

Tags: javascript, koa, ctx

I am writing a program that sends a get request to a Koa backend, and retrieves the result using Fetch. The backend looks like

```
const koa = require('koa');
const router = require('koa-router');
const cors = require('koa2-cors');
const app = new koa();
app.use(cors());
const _ = router();
const port = 3000;

_.get('/', async (ctx) => {
    const result = "good morning";
    console.log(result);
    ctx.body = result;
});

app.use(_.routes());

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port`);
});
```

The frontend looks like

```
submitButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/`)
        .then(res => console.log(res));
});
```

I am sure that the backend is functional, as when I press the submit button, the backend console is able to print the result correctly. But my frontend console is not printing anything. I have tried using alert(res) too. What might be going wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, is the AJAX request being made at all?  What is the server's response?  Are there any errors on the browser console?

Comment: There are no errors in the browser console. It just simply doesn't show anything. The backend console is able to show the output correctly

Comment: Ok, and in your browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, is the AJAX request being made at all? What is the server's response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to parse response so

```
submitButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
fetch(`http://localhost:3000/`)
    .then(res => res.json()) 
    .then(data => console.log(data)) 
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
});
```

Comment: I added the line that parses json, but it still doesn't seem to work. (when I console.log or alert it doesn't show).

Comment: it seems that the issue is that the koa response isn't completed after setting ctx.body. Any advice on ending the response?

Comment: I don't know anything about koa but maybe try ctx.response.end(); after setting result

Comment: i don't think that's a valid function on ctx.response or it might have been deprecated. thanks for the input though.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).